# How to write code for Selenium webdriver in Java for below HTML

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

HTML:

```html
<div id="Toolbar" style="color: rgb(35, 35, 34);">
    <ul class="dropdownMenu" style="display: none;"></ul>
    <div id="LeftToolbar" style="display: inline-block; width: 495px;">
        <ul class="dropdownMenu">
            <li>
                <div id="ScreenLayout" class="icon ScreenLayout group show" title="Screen Layout Selection">
                    <div id="ScreenLayoutIcon" class="icon show SCREEN1x1" title="Screen Layout 1x1" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
                    <div id="ScreenLayoutArrow" class="icon DROPDOWNARROW show" title="" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

I want to select "ScreenLayoutIcon" using Selenium + Java.

My code:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("LeftToolbar"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ScreenLayout']//ul")).click();
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
    if (option.getText().equals("Screen Layout")) {
        option.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: The HTML you posted was not valid and looks like you trimmed too much. The code you posted also would not compile because of several issues. Take a few minutes to read and understand what a [mcve] is. Reduce your code to an MCVE and post it. Also edit your question and add the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.

1. Your first line of code does nothing.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("LeftToolbar"));
   ```

   You are fetching an element from the page but you don't do anything with it and don't store it in a variable.
2. In the second line, the XPath is not valid syntax.

   ```
   //*@id='ScreenLayout']//ul
      ^ you are missing an '['
   ```

   It should be

   ```
   //*[@id='ScreenLayout']//ul
   ```

   BUT... there is no UL under the DIV that has the ID of 'ScreenLayout' according to the HTML you posted.
3. Your loop is looking for the LI that contains the text "Screen Layout" but according to the HTML you posted, none of them do.

The only reference to "ScreenLayoutIcon" I see is the ID for this DIV

```
<div id="ScreenLayoutIcon" class="icon show SCREEN1x1" title="Screen Layout 1x1" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
```

If you HTML is correct (I suspect it is not), this should click the element you are asking for.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ScreenLayoutIcon"));
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, you're going to have to update your HTML and post a link to the page.